# Numpy array specific operations

Tags: python

I have a numpy array of 512 tiff images. And I need to select 4 images every time to operate some calculations on them .and choose the next 4 images and operate the same operation and so on....

Comment: One Numpy array has 512 images?

Comment: Are these color images? As in the R,G,B elements are different?

Answer (score 1):

Just reshape the array and then use slicing to get 4 images at a time:

```
new_array = array.reshape(4, 128)
for i in range(128):
    batch_of_pictures = new_array[:, i] # or maybe the reverse
```

Note, this wasn't tested and may result in errors. The basic idea is sound though and you can refer to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html#indexing-slicing-and-iterating or leave a comment if you get stuck!

Since you actually have an array of a different size than I thought, try:

```
for i in range(0, 128, 4):
    batch_of_pictures = your_array[:,:,i:i+4]
```

Again, I haven't tested it but it should do fine! Your problem is just about indexing, so shift the i:i+3 to whatever position yields the correct picture array

Comment: Thank you but actually the array not of size 512 it is of (512*512*512) 512 image each one is 512*512 pixel and the array represents the pixel intensity values

Comment: `i:i+3` won't work, as Python (unlike R) doesn't include the last index. It should be `i:i+4`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the images are enumerated along the axis 0 of your array `img`:

```
N = 512 # the total number of images in img
for i in range(0, N, 4):
  img4 = img[i:i+4, :, :]       # img4 is now an array[4, 512, 512] of 4 images
  varImg = np.var(img4, axis=0) # computes the variance in img4, pixel-wise
```

Also, please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thank you very much ..could you please tell me how to create a counter and feed the function with it to operate the same calculation for every img4.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If by "counter" you mean `N`, I have edited the answer and set it to 512. It is the number of images in your array. You can define a function, e.g. `operate(x)`, using the `def` keyword in Python an pass it `img4` as the argument. You'll have to be more specific in your questions if you need a more detailed answer.

Comment: simply :now I got the correct array every element in this array represents 4 images:
now I want to do 
np.var(array[0]) which is calculating the variance of the first 4 images and want to save it as an image. after that do the same function for the second 4 images and so on....
you understand me??

Comment: I want to make a counter from 0 to 127  which represent the 1st 4images and second an so on....... ..And feed the function with it to calculate the variance of every 4 images in the array

Comment: I edited the post. Your "counter" is `i`, it goes from 0 to 511 in steps of 4. Divide it simply by 4 if you need it to be in range 0:127, e.g. for creating a file name.

Comment: BTW, if you are satisfied with the answer, consider accepting it.